# Unable to find plugins in list of available plugins in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have installed `Jenkins` by deploying its WAR file to `Tomcat`. On typing

```
http://localhost:8080/jenkins
```

In browser, `jenkins` home page is opening which means `jenkins` is successfully installed. I configured system settings, gave `jdk` and maven path and save them. Then to install plugins, I clicked on Jenkins->Manage plugins and clicked on Available tab but could not find any plugins. I tried three solutions:

1. Configured proxy for Jenkins by going to `Jenkins->Manage Plugins->Advanced`(did not find plugins)
2. Restarted server, refreshed browser and went to `Jenkins->Manage plugins->Available` (still did not find any plugins). So, I read somewhere that we have update plugins forcefully if they are not updated automatically. So, went to `Jenkins->Manage Plugins->Advanced` and clicked the tab 'Check now' (Still did not find any plugins on clicking on Available tab).
3. Finally I read somewhere that if we add the pluginGroup 'org.jvnet.hudson.tools' to settings.xml file of maven, problem may be resolved. So, added the corresponding code to settings.xml:

Then I tried again but still could not find any plugins in

```
Jenkins->Manage plugins->Available
```

If any other solution is there which can resolve this problem please let me know.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem may be that your **browser** proxy settings are not configured properly.

Jenkins doesn't retrieve the plugin list directly from the update center, it tells your browser to retrieve it and post it back to Jenkins.  So the HTTP proxy settings within Jenkins are ignored for this step.

So if you are using a browser that is configured to only work within your network, to connect to local servers such as a Jenkins instance, then you won't be able to update the plugin list.

(This just happened to me and took a frustrating hour to work out.)

Comment: I am facing same kind of issue. How am I supposed to resolve this?

Comment: This ended up being the correct answer for me, eventually... For whatever reasons, how each field was configured was incredibly picky. I posted an answer below with the details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39603125/3543437

Comment: Well something changes in our corp infra over the weekend - so while Jenkins gives `503 for URL: http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/update-center.json` in "Manage Plugins", I can see the JSON at that URL in the same browser...

Comment: Note that it only happens if you enable "Use browser for metadata download" in the global security, and only for metadata, not for the actual packages.

Answer (score 65):

Go to: Manage Jenkins → Manage Plugins → Advanced, then click Check now in the bottom right-hand corner. When you go back to Available tab all plugins should be listed.

Comment: it works, just make sure you configure Jenkins proxy and submit before clicking the checkout button.

Comment: That was the fix for me. :)

Answer (score 34):

At the plugins section of Jenkins open the "Advanced Settings" tab and paste the following URL into the Update Server URL field (at the bottom): https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json

Comment: It worked for me thanks , i updated the url and then went into the available and hit check now , seems to work ! thanks

Comment: Thanks, saved my Friday evening!

Comment: As of 2023 you don't need to do that since Jenkins itself includes that.

Answer (score 27):

For me the following worked:

Go to Manage Jenkins->Configure Global Security

Click the checkbox for "Use browser for metadata download"

I also have security disabled and prevent cross site forgery unchecked.

Comment: Oddly enough, this worked for me too, even though they say this is not recommended.

Comment: This was the fix for me. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Just Works. i am using jenkins-2.89.3 mac.

Comment: You are a life saver. Nothing else worked for me strangely.

Comment: Can't see this option in Jenkins 2.248

Comment: Option was removed: https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/pull/3970

Answer (score 23):

You can force update the plugin list by hand.

This worked for me:

```
wget -O default.js http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/update-center.json
sed '1d;$d' default.js > default.json
curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -d @default.json http://localhost:8080/updateCenter/byId/default/postBack --verbose
```

(I created this in order to be able to deploy Jenkins and install plugins in batch)

Comment: Thankyou.. But could you please let me know Where and how do I use this code ?

Comment: Do that on any linux box that has access to Jenkins without authentication, simply adapt the jenkins url to yours (i.e. localhost:8080 might be localhost:8080/jenkins

Comment: In op's case the URL would be http://localhost:8080/jenkins/updateCenter/byId/default/postBack

Comment: Cool that worked for me .. jenkins version 1.590 in x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: This causes my system to throw an exception on the curl statment. 
`javax.servlet.ServletException: org.acegisecurity.AccessDeniedException: browser-based download disabled` Any idea how I can get past this?

Comment: Just tested again, works fine for me. Do you have any access configuration set ?

Answer (score 11):

This was *so* frustrating... Not because of difficulty but lack of clarity and good documentation, at least for the issues I encountered. I ended up having to set up the Manage Plugins -> Advanced -> HTTP Proxy Configuration in a *very* specific, picky way. If I didn't do exactly this, minus the last noted thing on the bottom, I could not get this working. Maybe it's my work's firewall, maybe it's jenkins, either way give this a shot if you haven't been able to successfully update your proxy settings. I used the `Validate Proxy` tool in the menu. I'll very briefly describe the infographic basics below

[image]

1. Don't add `http://` or `https://` to your `Server` field
2. Use your jenkins credentials for `Username` and `Password`, not your proxy credentials (if that's even applicable)
3. Add `http://` to your `Test URL` if you're checking something like Google or Yahoo
4. Submit your changes
5. Then run check-now
6. (Optional?) Change Update site from HTTP to HTTPS

You should be able to now update your plugins *fingers-crossed*

Comment: wow.. who would've thought the username refers to the jenkins auth, not the proxy auth :) thanks!

Comment: For me it was point 6: change http to https, because Chrome refrained to download from http while the jenkins itself is https

Answer (score 9):

Change the update site from
https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json
to
http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/update-center.json

Comment: Click the "up arrow" Ashish :-)

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue when using nginx as a secure reverse proxy. I needed to update the url from which to download the updates list, as suggested above, only with https to prevent mixed content errors in chrome.

Comment: This didn't work for me, even though I'm dealing with the same issue. Just an FYI.

Answer (score 5):

The reason why I could not find a plugin that i searched for in `Jenkins->Manage plugins->Available`:

It had already been installed and it was in `Jenkins->Manage plugins->Installed`.

Comment: I hit this because things were installed as dependencies. Not always obvious!

Comment: Ouch, that saved it for me too ... m(

Answer (score 4):

I came across this SO answer while I was experiencing the same issue.  When I would click "Check Now" to force Jenkins to download the latest list, my browser would just hang.  It wasn't until I tailed the Jenkins log that I found this here:

```
Mar 10, 2014 1:15:54 PM hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter doFilter
WARNING: No valid crumb was included in request for /administrativeMonitor/hudson.diagnosis.ReverseProxySetupMonitor/test.  Returning 403.
```

Looks like the issue has to do with how I've put Jenkins behind a reverse proxy and enabled the option to prevent Cross Site Request Forgery.  Once I disabled that, the "Check Now" completed within 30 seconds.

Comment: Where is this log located/log name?

Answer (score 2):

For me, the following works out. I experience this empty available list issue after a fresh install jenkins 1.638 on Ubuntu 1404 in virtual box. We're under an ISA proxy server.

Go to `Jenkins->Manage Plugins->Advanced` and setup the proxy as below:

`Host: 192.168.x.x` (your Proxy IP)

`Port: 80` (Your proxy port)

Note that I find the format **matters**. I tried adding `http://` it doesn't work. It has to be exactly like above.

Then hit the `check now` button in the bottom right as everyone else suggested. Then you get the list.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is here

If you type in "http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/update-center.json" directory to brower's address bar, (in my case) it actually redirected to "http://ftp.tsukuba.wide.ad.jp/software/jenkins/updates/current/update-center.json."

It worked when I set "http://ftp.tsukuba.wide.ad.jp/software/jenkins/updates/current/update-center.json" to Jenkins' update site, and click "Save" & "Update."

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Or your plugin can be already installed. Once it's installed it's not in the list of available plugins.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Chrome 
Go to: Manage Jenkins → Manage Plugins → Advanced, then click `Check now` in the bottom right-hand corner. Then click a shield icon in the address bar, click `Load anyway` and Jenkins will start to update plugins. In Firefox this icon is situated on the left side of address bar, near back button.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can install plugins manually, to this this, go to advanced tab in manage plugins, after downloading plugins you need, submit these

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue with NginX proxy requests to Jenkins. I had error:

```
Nginx 413 Request Entity Too Large
```

I was able to fix that by adding

```
client_max_body_size 2M;
```

to the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file. After that I went to Jenkins - Plugin Manager - Advanced tab and press Check Now button

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and was able to resolve it by enabling the browser metadata download. Please follow the steps below the enable this configuration in Jenkins

- Step 01: Select Manage Jenkins and click on Configure Global Security
- Step 02: Under the Plugin Manager section tick the "Use browser for metadata download"
- Step 03: View Available tab under the Plugin Manager section in Manage Jenkins

Answer (score 1):

If its a fresh installation not behind proxy please follow instruction under available "Use the search field above to search for available plugins".

[image]

Comment: How can I see all available plugins as before.  How can I enter its name if I don't know it exists?.

Answer (score 0):

After trying many things (including all the solutions posted here) and hours of searching... I've ended up with the ***upgrade of jenkins to version 1.638***.

This helps to solve the frustrated problem with empty available plugins in older version of jenkins!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is specific to **Windows 10**. If you use the installer that Jenkins now comes bundled as, Jenkins will get installed as a service. By default, the service runs under the **Local System** account. You have to change it to run under the **Network Service** account in order for Jenkins to be able to connect with the plugin update service. If you have Administrator privileges on the system then these steps should help:

1. Open Command Prompt.
2. Type in Services.msc and hit enter.
3. The Services window should be open now.
4. Locate the Jenkins instance in the list.
5. Right click on it and click Properties.
6. Go to the Log On tab (should be the second one).
7. There should be 2 radio buttons.

   - Local System Account (selected)
   - This Account (unselected)
8. Select This Account.
9. Type in **Network Service** in the text box.
10. Provide your windows password.
11. Hit Apply and OK.
12. Restart the Jenkins service.
13. Reload Jenkins in browser.

For added measures, you could also add a rule in Windows Firewall (or any other Firewall that you may be using) to allow outbound requests from Jenkins. Point to the **jenkins.exe** application that should be located in the installation directory of Jenkins for this rule.

Comment: This made my Jenkins instance not be able to start back up after switching to Network Service.

Answer (score 0):

For those like me who use Jenkins with Docker with a JDK8u60+ version, you need to remove the MD5 hash in JDK_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security to make it works:

```
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, RSA keySize < 1024

To

jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, RSA keySize < 1024
```

This should be a temporary workaround

Answer (score 0):

You don't have internet connection on Jenkins Machine.please configure Internet or installed plugin in offline mode.

Go to Jenkins -Plugin Manager-Upload Plugin

Answer (score 0):

My Environment

- Windows 7 Enterprise
- Jenkins 2.89.2
- Direct access to Internet

I tried most of the suggestions provided here but nothing worked until I tried following

**First:** I needed to run as 'Administrator'

**Second:** It was using default user home dir at C:\users\yourusername\.jenkins.

**What Worked:**

I changed default dir above to a different folder by defining JENKINS_HOME environment variable and I was able to get new plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with the latest Jenkins version, and all solutions didn't work with me so I followed the command line approach to install any plugin

```
sudo java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ -auth USERNAME:PASSWORD -webSocket install-plugin PLUGIN_NAME
```

You can download the Jenkins-cli.jar from the installed Jenkins page http://localhost:8080/cli

You can search for the plugin name from the Jenkins site
https://plugins.jenkins.io/

> If you have the Jenkins CLI installed uou can run this command
> directly via terminal

```
jenkins-plugin-cli --plugins PLUGIN_NAME
```

I hope this solution helps if others didn't work with you.

Answer (score 0):

I too tried all above,but this worked wonders

steps:

1. Go to  `https://plugins.jenkins.io` (official page to get all jenkins plugins you are looking to install on jenkins)
2. Search "github" ( as we need github plugin to install)
3. You will see the github plugin,check the plugin id...it displays as   id:github....so "github" is the exact plugin id
4. Download the `jenkins-cli.jar`  from `http://localhost:8080/cli` and copy  under `/opt/jenkins-cli.jar` in jenkins server
5. On jenkins server ,run the command  to install github plugin
   `java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s "http://localhost:8080"  -auth jenkins-username:jenkins-password install-plugin  github`
6. Restart server
7. Now u will see the github plugin installed under installed section

Answer (score 0):

For those who used Docker with MacOS. When you use Docker, there is no need to configure proxy settings for Jenkins inside Jenkins application, but you can and should do it already when running the container. For the context, I use MacOS and I was working within enterprise domain that had proxy configured.

**SOLUTION**

1. **Configure proxy settings for Docker.** You can do that if you open Preferences in Docker Desktop. The left menu, "[Resources](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/#resources)"->"Proxies". There you need to add correct proxy settings and then click "Apply & restart"
2. **Add proxy settings to container when running it by giving and env variables HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY.** Add following flags with correct values to your command:`-e HTTP_PROXY=<your_http_proxy:port> -e HTTPS_PROXY=<your_http_proxy:port>`. An example with my own proxy configuration:

```
docker run \
-p 8080:8080 \
-p 50000:50000 \
-e HTTP_PROXY=http://10.65.100.13:8080 \
-e HTTPS_PROXY=http://10.65.100.13:8080 \
-v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home \
jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11
```

**UNDERLYING ISSUE**

The issue was SSL certificates. Jenkins, when downloading plugins, was unable to reach the CA certificates while working inside the container that was no configured to work using proxy. This caused the download to fail. Even if I configured Jenkins proxy settings as suggested in previous answers, it was no good, because the container itself failed to communicate over proxy.

Reading the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/#resources), I found out that Docker should access CA certs itself from keychain, but it does not add proxy settings automatically to containers. Configuration to the container has to be added manually. Doing so configures the whole container properly in terms of proxy and container is able to reach for CA certs. Once the container works via proxy as expected, Jenkins does not need additional configuration itself.