# Not able to find "Maven Project" radio button while creating new job in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins. I have followed all the steps. I have downloaded `jenkins.war` and placed it in `webapps` directory of my Tomcat. Once I start my Tomcat and give the URL `localhost:8080/jenkins` I get Jenkins dashboard. I have configured `JDK_HOME` and `MAVEN_HOME` by giving the path of my local. Now, when I try to create new job, I am only getting **Freestyle project** option as shown below:

[image]

However I want to create a Maven project here.

I have also downloaded `maven-plugin.hpi` file and added it in `.j2/plugins` folder.

But no plugin is shown in the dashboard. I am stuck here. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 4):

On latest version of Jenkins, under Manage Plugins I have installed "Maven Integration Plugin" and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to install https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Maven+Project+Plugin additionally. Take a look at Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins if this plugin is installed.

Comment: I have installed the same plugin and added it in .j2/plugins folder. But nothing is shown in the dashboard.

Comment: Do you see this plugin in "Available" tab? Probably you can use Jenkins GUI to install it?

Comment: No I don't see that plugin in "Available" tab.

Comment: Do you use latest Jenkins version?

Comment: Yes I have downloaded the latest version i.e Jenkins 2.2 from https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/war/

Comment: Do you see any plugin in "Available" tab? Maybe that will help to solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213982/unable-to-find-plugins-in-list-of-available-plugins-in-jenkins

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111622/discussion-between-shruthi-sathyanarayana-and-andrej-istomin).