# Jenkins Update Center broken -- java.io.IOException: Downloaded file /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/*.jpi.tmp does not match expected SHA-1

Tags: jenkins, plugins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I had to make some changes to the Jenkins config.xml to roll back some new changes that broke a lot of stuff since the configHistory plugin only allows rolling back of jobs.

Also ended up having to backup and write new XMLs for other configuration XMLs to what they were before today's changes. Stored those in a subdir, but didn't touch any associated files, like filename.log, etc.

Now, I can't seem to update or install any new plugins. I always get this error for each plugin:

> java.io.IOException: Downloaded file
>   /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/.jpi.tmp does not match expected
>   SHA-1

[image]

Screenshot for some extra reference.

I have no idea what is broken or how to unbreak it... But this Jenkins servers has a bunch of jobs that heavily rely on plugins. I'm trying to do this without wrecking all those configs if possible. Advice?

When I'm in the update center, if I select a plugin I've never had installed before, and use "Check now" instead of download, I get this error:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Could not find (numeric) updateCenterVersion...

### Edit: [This ended up being my fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39603125/3543437)

Comment: Can you just restart jenkins server once again? If possible, restart the computer(if it's hosted on one) or the whole server hosting it and then restart jenkins job.

Comment: @xCodeZone Rebooting and also "Restart Safely" didn't work. When I went to the update center and ran check instead of download, I got this error followed by a wall of text: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find (numeric) updateCenterVersion...

Comment: Have a look at this one. there are a few proposed solutions. Check if any works. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213982/unable-to-find-plugins-in-list-of-available-plugins-in-jenkins

Comment: @xCodeZone None of those panned out... :(

Comment: Okay, let me do the exact something that you did. I have a test jenkins running that's configured to no job. Let me see what I can do.

Comment: @xCodeZone Thank you!!!

Comment: I ran into this issue yesterday. But it works now. So maybe there is something wrong in your network and you can try later.

Comment: It ended up being a network issue. The following answer was what I had to do to resolve it. I initially referenced the accepted answer, but apparently was not implementing it correctly, thus the more detailed answer I submitted. I'm fine closing this. I'll start the vote and leave it to the community: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39603125/3543437