# Why OWASP Dependency-Check Plugin is not finding anything?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, owasp

In a pipeline I run two baseline commands that generate and publish the report within a repo. But the problem is there are 0 warinings in the results

The commands in jenkins:

```
 dependencyCheckAnalyzer datadir: '', hintsFile: '', includeCsvReports: false, includeHtmlReports: false, includeJsonReports: false, includeVulnReports: false, isAutoupdateDisabled: false, outdir: '', scanpath: '', skipOnScmChange: false, skipOnUpstreamChange: false, suppressionFile: '', zipExtensions: ''
 dependencyCheckPublisher canComputeNew: false, defaultEncoding: '', healthy: '', pattern: '**/dependency-check-report.xml', unHealthy: ''
```

What it does it outputs with:

```
[DependencyCheck] OWASP Dependency-Check Plugin v3.1.1
[DependencyCheck] Executing Dependency-Check with the following options:
[DependencyCheck]  -name = myDependencycheckerjob
[DependencyCheck]  -scanPath = /mypath
[DependencyCheck]  -outputDirectory = /mypath
[DependencyCheck]  -dataDirectory = /mypath/dependency-check-data
[DependencyCheck]  -dataMirroringType = none
...
[DependencyCheck]  -opensslAnalyzerEnabled = true
[DependencyCheck]  -showEvidence = true
[DependencyCheck]  -formats = XML 
[DependencyCheck]  -autoUpdate = true
[DependencyCheck]  -updateOnly = false
[DependencyCheck] Data directory created
[DependencyCheck] Scanning: /mypath
[DependencyCheck] Analyzing Dependencies
[Pipeline] dependencyCheckPublisher
[DependencyCheck] Collecting Dependency-Check analysis files...
[DependencyCheck] Searching for all files in /mypath that match the pattern     **/dependency-check-report.xml
[DependencyCheck] Parsing 1 file in /mypath
[DependencyCheck] Successfully parsed file /mypath/dependency-check-report.xml with 0 unique warnings and 0 duplicates.
[DependencyCheck] Computing warning deltas based on reference build #3
```

Now the file in dependency-check-data is quite big, around 200mb, the report is generated but there are 0 found issues (seems to be regardles on whats in the root folder of the project).

What is missing here that prevends the output of being generated?

The html report indicates that there is just one single dependency, which is gradle-wrapper.jar

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213982/unable-to-find-plugins-in-list-of-available-plugins-in-jenkins?rq=1#