# Jenkins available plugin list empty

Tags: list, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I'm using jenkins running in a docker container inside virtual box, with network bridged adapter. I want to install jenkin plugin blue ocean for pipeline manage. The problem is that available plugin list is empty in manage plugin section of jenkins. I searched solutions from [Unable to find plugins in list of available plugins in jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213982/unable-to-find-plugins-in-list-of-available-plugins-in-jenkins/39603125) but none of the proposed solutions works. I am wondering if there's any other ways to fix it. I guess I need to config proxy but i don't know how to config with jenkins running in a container, and i don't understand well the nature of proxy.
Thanks.

Comment: What jenkins version do you have? As of [LTS 2.235.1](https://www.jenkins.io/changelog-stable/#v2.235.1) , "Various *improvements* to the plugin manager, including: It no longer shows all available plugins by default; use search field to find plugins.". Jenkins proxy is under the advanced tab ( `{JENKINSURL}/pluginManager/advanced`)

Comment: @Ian W As you suggested, although no available plugins show, but i still can find plugin through search field. Thank you. By the way, I think i don't have to do anything with proxy configuration.